# How to use KDM instead of lightdm in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, lightdm, kdm

I need to configure KDM by system settings, because lightDM is not working any more (I don't know why, just stopped working), so, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>Control+Alt+F1</kbd> and in the terminal that appears login and run

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm